# Get path to folder using zenity

Tags: zenity

I found the zenity file path dialog but I how can I get the path to a folder?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a folder's path you can use the same as for files, but adding the `--directory` option.

> So you can run:
>
> `zenity --file-selection --directory`
>
> and then you'll obtain the path of selected folder.

You can get more info about these options issuing `zenity --help-file-selection` on terminal.